# Cant install python2 modules (kali 2020)

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, python, pip

```
$ pip install impacket                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    Requirement already satisfied: impacket in /home/kali/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (0.9.16.dev0)

$ sudo python2 -m pip install impacket  
    /usr/bin/python2: No module named pip
```

I found this:

```
$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o pip2.py

$ sudo python2 pip2.py install impacket      
Collecting install  
Using cached install-1.3.0.tar.gz (1.8 kB)
    
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /usr/bin/python2 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-JsNXwt/install/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-JsNXwt/install/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-zr9fqs
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-JsNXwt/install/
    Complete output (6 lines):
    usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
       or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
       or: setup.py --help-commands
       or: setup.py cmd --help
    
    error: invalid command 'egg_info'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Do `command -v pip`, `pip freeze`, or `pip list` provide any output?

Answer (score 1):

Python2 is deprecated, here is how to correctly install python2 on Kali Linux Rolling Release based on Kali docs: [Using EoL Python Versions on Kali](https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/using-eol-python-versions/)

> Python 2 is no longer being maintained in the Debian repositories. This means that we must find a way to work around this issue. pyenv solves this problem by allowing us to install multiple versions of Python that do not conflict with each other.

pyenv is your way to install python2:

```
sudo apt install -y build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev \
libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev \
libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev python3-openssl git

curl https://pyenv.run |bash 
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then  eval "$(pyenv init -)" ; fi
exec $SHELL
pyenv
pyenv install 2.7.18
pyenv global 2.7.18
python2 -m pip install impacket
```

Then run python2 and check impacket version:

```
python2
>>> from impacket import version
>>> version.BANNER
```

sample output:

```
'Impacket v0.9.18 - Copyright 2018 SecureAuth Corporation\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out
$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py

$ python get-pip.py

Now pip2 will work and install into python2 directories

I must have messed up something prior to this. Anyway, now we can install modules for python2

Comment: For those considering this approach: You should watch out! I know this is from pypa.io but it is generally an extremely bad idea to just download scripts from the internet and execute them. At least you should look into the script before executing to see what it does. Also, the fact that there is a huge binary-blob in the script should make you feel very uncomfortable... Take care!